# Found ** in Ocaml, but not for exponentiation

Tags: syntax, ocaml, first-order-logic

In a book about logics ([https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/OCaml/real.ml](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/atp/OCaml/real.ml)), I find this kind of code:

```
let integer_qelim =
   simplify ** evalc **
   lift_qelim linform (cnnf posineq ** evalc) cooper;;
```

I have seen `**` before, but it was for exponentiation purposes, whereas here I do not think it is used for that, as the datatypes are not numeric. I would say it is some king of function combinator, but no idea.

I think this book was written for a version 3.06, but an updated code for 4 (https://github.com/newca12/ocaml-atp) maintains this, so `**` is still used in that way that I do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OCaml, you can bind to operators any behavior, e.g.,

```
let ( ** ) x y = print_endline x; print_endline y
```

so that `"hello" ** "world"` would print

```
hello
world
```

In the code that you reference, the [(**)](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/atp/OCaml/atp_interactive.ml) operator is bound to function composition:

```
let ( ** ) = fun f g x -> f(g x)
```

Comment: Oohh, I had not seen it and it was on one of the first lines. So this is a particular case where a function has been named with **. I hadn't thought of that idea, because I thought ** would be a reserved word and that declaring a function with its name was not possible. Sorry mate, for always making you answer :)

Comment: (I know you know that but there's a typo and this comment is for others ;-)) Actually you need to declare it as `let ( ** ) = (* ... *)` because the syntax for comments and custom operators becomes the same when you start using `*` which is a pain. A minor one but a pain nonetheless

Comment: It's great practice to try defining some operators for yourself. For instance, I was recently writing a `is_leap_year` function as a demonstration for a student, and found myself writing a lot of boolean tests like: `year mod 4 = 0`. To make my life easier I defined an operator `%?` as a locally scoped function to do this for me. `let (%?) a b = a mod b = 0`. So instead of `year mod 4 = 0 && year mod 100 <> 0` I can write `year %? 4 && not (year %? 100)`. I could have taken it even farther and used `let (%!) a b = a mod b <> 0` to write `year %? 4 && year %! 100`.

Comment: @Lhooq thanks for noticing this, and Jeffrey thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1):

That's an utility-function defined in [`lib.ml`](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/atp/OCaml/lib.ml):

```ml
let ( ** ) = fun f g x -> f(g x);;
```

It's a composition-operator, often referred to as `compose` in other examples.

You can use it like this:

```ml
let a x = x^"a" in
let b x = x^"b" in
let c x = x^"c" in
let foo = a ** b ** c in
foo "input-";;
- : string = "input-cba"
```

You could write it as

```ml
let foo x = a (b (c x))
```

or

```ml
let foo x = a @@ b @@ c x
```

or

```ml
let foo x = c x |> b |> a
```

as well.